# Deleting cookies in iOS application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Do I read the [NSHTTPCookieStorage documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSHTTPCookieStorage/deleteCookie%3a) right that you can't delete other cookies than on those belonging to your own app? So if you loop through all the cookies you get from that object you only get those cookies associated with your application such as those retrieved in a webview?

> iOS Note: Cookies are not shared among applications in iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you read it correctly. The previous line in the doc (`These cookies are shared among all applications and are kept in sync cross-process`) is there for OS X. Cookie sharing among apps would be an enormous security violation. And though I haven't tried it, I'm confident that yes, enumerating cookies on iOS just gives you those stored for your app.